# Unable to run "yo @microsoft/sharepoint"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, nodejs

I am trying to run my first SPFX as mentioned on this link @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension .. but when i run `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` i got this error:-

[image]

so i run this command `install -g yo gulp` but i got this error:-

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following

- run your console as an administrator
- run `npm uninstall -g gulp`
- run `npm install -g yo`
- run `npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint -g`

then try:

- create a new folder
- navigate to a folder
- run `yo`
- follow generator's instructions
- when you are done, run `npm install -g gulp`